# Elastica searches the elasticsearch index, but gives entity from mysql

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, elastica

I am using FOS Elastica. I indexed a page from mysql with title Homez with the command 'php bin/console fos:elastica:populate'. Then I changed the title in mysql to Homek. But when I search a page with title Homez in my controller:

```
use Elastica\Query;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\FinderInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class HomepageController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(
        private FinderInterface $finder,
    ) {
    }

    #[Route('/', name: 'homepage')]
    public function view(): Response
    {
        $query = new Query([
            'query' => [
                'match' => [
                    'title' => 'Homez',
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        return $this->render('homepage/view.html.twig', [
            'page' => $this->finder->find($query)[0],
        ]);
    }
}
```

I get the values from the mysql database (title is Homek).

In config/packages/fos_elastica.yaml I have:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
      default: { host: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_HOST)%', port: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_PORT)%' }
    indexes:
      page:
        properties:
          id: ~
          title: ~
          slug: ~
          summary: ~
          content: ~
          publishedAt: ~
          author_id: ~
        persistence:
          driver: orm
          model: App\Entity\Page
```

And in App\Entity\Page I have:

```
use App\Repository\PageRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

#[
    ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PageRepository::class),
    ORM\Table(name: "page"),
    ORM\UniqueConstraint(name: "title_unique", fields: ["title"]),
    ORM\UniqueConstraint(name: "slug_unique", fields: ["slug"]),
    UniqueEntity(fields: ["title"], message: "There is already a page with this title."),
    UniqueEntity(fields: ["slug"], message: "There is already a page with this slug."),
]
class Page
{
    #[
        ORM\Id,
        ORM\Column(type: "integer"),
        ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: "IDENTITY"),
    ]
    private int $id;

    #[
        ORM\Column(type: "string"),
        Assert\NotBlank,
    ]
    private string $title;

    #[
        ORM\Column(type: "string"),
        Assert\NotBlank,
    ]
    private string $slug;

    #[
        ORM\Column(type: "string", nullable: true),
        Assert\Length(max: 255),
    ]
    private ?string $summary = null;

    #[
        ORM\Column(type: "text"),
        Assert\Length(min: 10),
    ]
    private string $content;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "integer")]
    private int $publishedAt;

    #[
        ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: "User", inversedBy: "pages"),
        ORM\JoinColumn(name: "author_id", referencedColumnName: "id", nullable: false),
    ]
    private User $author;
}
```

And in App\Repository\PageRepository I have:

```
use App\Entity\Page;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class PageRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements PageRepositoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private EntityManagerInterface $em,
        ManagerRegistry $registry,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($registry, Page::class);
    }
```

So my question is: how can I get the Page entity with values from elasticsearch instead of mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\PaginatedFinderInterface;

class UserController
{
    private $finder;

    public function __construct(PaginatedFinderInterface $finder)
    {
        $this->finder = $finder;
    }

    public function userAction()
    {
        // Option 1. Returns all users who have example.net in any of their mapped fields
        $results = $this->finder->find('example.net');

        // Option 2. Returns a set of hybrid results that contain all Elasticsearch results
        // and their transformed counterparts. Each result is an instance of a HybridResult
        $results = $this->finder->findHybrid('example.net');

        // Option 3a. Pagerfanta'd resultset
        /** var Pagerfanta\Pagerfanta */
        $userPaginator = $this->finder->findPaginated('bob');
        $countOfResults = $userPaginator->getNbResults();

        // Option 3b. KnpPaginator resultset
        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $results = $this->finder->createPaginatorAdapter('bob');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate($results, $page, 10);

        // You can specify additional options as the fourth parameter of Knp Paginator
        // paginate method to nested_filter and nested_sort

        $options = [
            'sortNestedPath' => 'owner',
            'sortNestedFilter' => new Query\Term(['enabled' => ['value' => true]]),
        ];

        // sortNestedPath and sortNestedFilter also accepts a callable
        // which takes the current sort field to get the correct sort path/filter

        $pagination = $paginator->paginate($results, $page, 10, $options);
    }
}
```

FOSElasticBundle has pretty cool documentation with examples, you can find it here: [FOSElasticaBundle Usage](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/usage.md#foselasticabundle-usage)